# Meaning of the last paragraph ( in bold text )

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, british-english, late-modern-english

That night we were to have Mr Chamberlain as our dinner guest. ‘I am dining in very bad company,’ he observed, surveying us with a challenging air. We explained how inept and arrogant the action of the Government had been. How could we be expected to support it? ‘What is the use,’ he replied, ‘of supporting your own Government only when it is right? It is just when it is in this sort of pickle that you ought to have come to our aid.’ However, as he mellowed, he became most gay and captivating. I never remember having heard him talk better.

As he rose to leave he paused at the door, and turning said with much deliberation, **‘You young gentlemen have entertained me royally, and in return I will give you a priceless secret. Tariffs! There are the politics of the future, and of the near future. Study them closely and make yourselves masters of them, and you will not regret your hospitality to me.’**

Comment: What part do you not understand? What research have you done?

Comment: @Cascabel  I don't understand the meaning of word Tariff in this context, I did a google search for the meaning of tariffs ( meaning is a charge or money paid for something )

Comment: A tariff is a duty or tax paid on certain types of imports or exports. As an example, Trump has based much of his political career on imposing tariffs on Chinese imports in order to offset an imbalance in trade. It hasn't accomplished all that it was supposed to, but it was  seen politically as a popular move.

Comment: @Cascabel What will it mean in this context ? I think it means something else in this context,

Comment: BTW.."THE PRESIDENT on Fox News’ “SUNDAY MORNING FUTURES”: “Just like last time, Bernie Sanders’ people are going to vote for me because of what I’ve done on trade.”

Comment: @Cascabel I'm not sure about the Opium Wars reference, unless you know of a senior politician called Chamberlain before Joseph. Joseph Chamberlain was only born in 1836 while the Opium Wars started in 1839 and were over by 1860. He wouldn't have been calling his hosts 'young gentlemen' at twenty four, let alone before he was three!

Comment: You are right, @BoldBen...I thought that was  a little off. I was looking at a bad date on a Google.books reference that placed the quote in the era of Queen Victoria. I was wondering who this other Chamberlain fellow was .. not Wilt, not Neville. A better search shows this quote comes from Churchill. Only off by a century or so...Damn my eyes, and txs.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the two paragraphs is that after a great deal of witty conversation, Chamberlain indirectly informs his young hosts that they are ignoring what's really important in government, which is concrete actions rather than philosophy.  This is, at any rate, one interpretation.

Thus, "tariffs" means "tariffs."

The two paragraphs are from a book by Winston S. Churchill titled "My Early Life." The book seems to have been published in 1930, but the events referred to are, according to the text, 1902-1908.

It would be helpful on such questions for the poster to indicate the source of the quotation.